# POO - Polimorfismo

Tags: java, poo, polimorfismo

El **polimorfismo** es un tema recurrente a dudas o que al menos no queda del todo claro.
He leído varias definiciones, pero me siguen confundiendo cuando trato de explicarlo, o dar ejemplos.
Hasta hace poco leí que existen varios tipos de polimorfismo y que no necesariamente tiene que haber una jerarquía de herencia para que suceda.

- Polimorfismo de sobrecarga
- Polimorfismo paramétrico
- Polimorfismo de inclusión

A su vez están los conceptos de **funciones polimórficas** y **tipos polimórficos**.

¿Podrían ayudarme a definirlas y dar ejemplos concretos en JAVA?

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que no entiendes en concreto? Este tipo de preguntas son muy amplias y a menudo basadas en opiniones. Recuerda que SO no es un sustituto de un buscador online.

Comment: Te dejo dos enlaces que dan respuesta a todas tus dudas: [_Polymorphism in Java with example_](https://beginnersbook.com/2013/03/polymorphism-in-java/) (en ese 1er enlace hay más enlaces...) y luego [_Types of polymorphism in java- Runtime and Compile time polymorphism_](https://beginnersbook.com/2013/04/runtime-compile-time-polymorphism/). Hay ejemplos explicativos y todo. El único problema es el de siempre, en estas cosas lo mejor existe en inglés, pues hay que aprender a leer en inglés. En cuanto a la pregunta, @AlvaroMontoro tiene razón, esto daría para escribir una biblioteca.